# How to add a keybinding containing a "+" sign to extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to add keybindings containing "+" (e.g. "shift"+"+") to a command of an extension on Linux. Apparently when manually adding such a keybinding to a command, it results to the following json structure (checking keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "shift+[BracketRight]",
  "command": "vscode-command"
}
```

Executing this keybinding using "shift"+"+" works.

When declaring this exact key to the package.json keybindings section of the extension and running it afterwards, this binding does not have any effect, the command is still not bound to any keybinding.

Other keybindings like "shift"+"-" and "shift"+"0" do work out of the box.

I've also seen "Ctrl"+"]" as keybindings of commands (maybe using other keyboard layouts), but putting in "]" as "[BracketRight]" replacement also had no effect.

On my Windows installation the key for the command seems to be "shift"+"oem_plus", but this is not recognized correctly on Linux.

I've also tried to use other key combinations containing a "+", but none of them resulted in a keybinding with "Extension" as source.

Does anyone know how to reliably bind keybindings containing "+" to an extension command on all platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac)?

Comment: Just a quick idea: have you tried escaping the ` +`  using a backslash?`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately "\" is not allowed inside the keybinding declaration.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 `+` keys on my keyboard

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> (in the vicinity of <kbd>0</kbd>)
- <kbd>Numpad Plus</kbd>

From the doc: [Accepted keys](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_accepted-keys)

We have to use `=` and `numpad_add` in the key binding definition.

The following key bindings work on Windows.

```
        "keybindings": [
          {
            "command": "myext.regularplus",
            "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+=",
            "when": "editorTextFocus"
          },
          {
            "command": "myext.numpadplus",
            "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+numpad_add",
            "when": "editorTextFocus"
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately on e.g. the german keyboard layout ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout#/media/File:KB_Germany.svg ) the "+" key is not at the same position as "=". I'm slowly coming to the conclusion that (except for Windows with its Virtual-Key system ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes )) it is not easily possible to reliably map characters like "+" keyboard layout independent to keybindings on each platform (except for numpad-assignments)

Comment: @e01306821 if you use the key binding debugging what key is shown if you press `+`, you can always create a bug issue because they use a low level keyboard code for the key bindings, it is missing some language specific translation, you have the same problem with the `Z` and `Y` key, the scan codes method also does not work, `[BracketRight]` on some keyboard might be mapped to backtick or something else

Comment: If you use the key binding GUI what key does it show when you press the `+` key in record key mode (Alt+K)

Comment: It shows `[BracketRight]` which seems to be the key positioned in the US keyboard layout at the same position as the `+` key of the german keyboard layout. I think mapping `[BracketRight]` for the desired keybinding (where `+` has to be involved) does not lead to the desired result. I've for now created an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130396
Thanks for your support

Comment: @e01306821 The consequence is that anyone using a US keyboard can't use your keybinding because they can't type `shift`+`+` because `+` is `shift`+`=`, I think you have to fall back to key combos `ctrl+k ctrl+p`, the Keyboard GUI seems to recognize combos like `ctrl+k =`

Comment: That's correct although using `shift+oem_plus` as keybinding for Windows results in a working keyboard shortcut for both layouts (also `shift+=` seems to work for the US layout assuming I conducted the test correctly). It would be nice to have a similar virtual key system available for Linux and Mac

Comment: @e01306821 that means there `layout-independent bindings` is incomplete, is `Toggle Word Wrap` on your German keyboard Alt+Z or Alt+Y, where on the doc page do they mention `oem_plus`, there is `VK_OEM_PLUS`

Comment: `Toggle Word Wrap` is bound onto `Alt+Z`. And yes, the doc does not mention `oem_plus`, but this sequence was the result of creating a Keyboard Shortcut on Windows manually containing `+`.